# Showing that an ideal is not principal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-21}]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I am trying to show that the ideal 
$$(2,\sqrt{-21}-1)(3, \sqrt{-21}) $$
is not principal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-21}]$. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Hint: what is the norm of this ideal? Is there an element of this norm in the ring?

Comment: The norm of this ideal would be 5, which implies there has to be an element $x \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-21}]$ that has norm five. This is not possible. Is this enough?

Comment: The norm is $6$, but yes, that argument works.

Comment: How have you gotten that the norm is 6? I have that $(2,\sqrt{-21}-1)(3, \sqrt{-21})=\mathfrak{p}_{5}$ where $\mathfrak{p}_{5}=(5, \sqrt{-21} -3)$. This has conjugate $(5, \sqrt{-21} -2)$ since $\mathfrak{p}_{5}\overline{\mathfrak{p}_{5}}$ is the prime factorisation of $(5)$, wouldn't this imply that the norm is 5?

Comment: How is this product $\mathfrak p_5$? Specifically, how is $5$ in the product of those ideals?

Comment: In fact, i think i may have made a mistake with that, can you explain to me how you computed the norm?

Comment: It's easiest to note the norm is multiplicative, and the two ideals you multiply have norms $2,3$.

Answer (score 0):

The Very Useful Theorem that you want to use is that if an ideal $\mathfrak a$ is principal, equal to $\langle b\rangle$, then the norm of $\mathfrak a$ is $\mathbf N(b)$, where $\mathbf N$ is the field-theoretic Norm map from the big field down to $\Bbb Q$.

In your case, since an integral basis for the integers of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-21}\,)$ can be taken to be $\{1,\sqrt{-21}\,\}$ (because $-21\not\equiv1\pmod4$ ), so the Norm of the general integer $m+n\sqrt{-21}$ is $m^2+21n^2$. I’m sure you can finish it all off from here.